# .ics attachment Issue in yahoo mail

Tags: python

I am sending meeting events from my service . so i am generating .ics file in icalendar format and sending to defferent mail clients.

My Aim is to get the event dates enter code here be imported to the calendar automatically and should be able to send response to my service by clicking ( yes, no , maybe   if gmail) Accept , decline, tentative.

in all other clients My goal has been achived except  Yahoo, and Hotmail.
In Yahoo Mail it is showing attachment as inline

can anybody please help why my ics file has not been understandable by yahoo and hotmail?

Thanks

Appu

Answer (score 1):

What a shame that Yahoo! Mail does not manage iCalendar events in Yahoo! Calendar yet, in 2011!

At least events are now provided as ICS attachments in "new" Yahoo! Mail and you can manage invitations manually. Maybe Yahoo! Classic did in the past. I will check and consider to revert possibly.

This is the only solution for people keeping on using Yahoo! Webmail service.

Have a look here, at [Yahoo! Developer Network](http://developer.yahoo.com/forum/General-Discussion-at-YDN/Problem-opening-ICS-files-from-Yahoo/1299668671000-24ed7a59-019f-3f1b-b596-70ab34db783c).

Hotmail (Windows Live Hotmail as of 2011) does really manage iCalendar events as a champ. As I am a new to Hotmail, I can't say how long it has been working like this. But Windows Live Hotmail Calendar is my favorite Webmail Calendar, compared to other free Webmail services available here in France.

Comment: 2019 still cant't simply respond & add to calendar, maybe next millenium ;)

Comment: 2021 still same. I hope my grandchilds can see that day.